# create a timestamp in php and replace old date

Tags: php, mysql, time

I would like to create an hourly timestamp in php such that it follows like this

```
Friday, July 1, 2011 01:00:00
Friday, July 1, 2011 02:00:00
Friday, July 1, 2011 03:00:00
.
.
.
```

how to create an hourly stamp?

```
Friday, July 1, 2011 01:00:00
```

my second question is :
after we have created these hourly stamps for 24 hours I would like to refresh the new time stamp with the old take this as an example to make clear what I am trying to achieve:

```
Saturday, July 2, 2011 00:00:00
Friday, July 1, 2011 01:00:00
Friday, July 1, 2011 02:00:00
Friday, July 1, 2011 03:00:00
```

here `Saturday replaced Friday's old 00:00:00`
is it possible to achieve this using php and mysql considering the above example was from a table with column 'timestamp'

Comment: Do you want to run a script every hour that adds a row to the database with the current timestamp? Or what do you want to do with the timestamps?

Comment: if a new visitor arrived I would increment other columns value, I am using this as a base.

Comment: it would be sufficient if you could teach me how i may able to produce that timestamp

Answer (score 0):

To get the format you wanted use the date() function and give the correct format as parameter

```
<?php
  //Format the current date and time
  $date = date("l, F j, Y H:i:s");
  echo $date;
?>
```

If you want to know more about formatting dates please read the date() manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: And here he can just ignore minute and second format and replace it with 0 to get just the hourly timestamp.

Comment: If you want to ignore the minutes and seconds, replace the 'i' and 's' with 00